# How do I get rid of reblog/like history on photo reblog page on tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

[image]

As in the photo above, I would like to get rid of the scroll bar along with the history of all the likes and reblogs which are located once you click on the photo on my blog. Where would I locate this in the custom CSS on tumblr and which code would I use?

I have been looking at this code, but not sure where to go next.

```
{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div class="photo"><a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=250px/></a></div>{LinkCloseTag}
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are a few ways to do it, the easiest is just to remove or comment out that code from your template. I would do assuming this is the reblog block I would just wrap it in a comment. `<!-- {block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div class="photo"><a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=250px/></a></div>{LinkCloseTag}
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons"> -->` keep a copy or your template locally and just experiment with commenting out the correct block.

Comment: @lharby I tried your method for a few other elements I wanted to remove and it works. Nevertheless, I am having a struggle locating the block responsible for the reblog history. I found this ```{block:PostNotes}
</center></center>
<div class="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes} 
</div>``` but when I try wrapping it my entire blog dissappears except for one picture

Comment: Can you paste your entire template into pastebin or jsfiddle. https://pastebin.com/ and then post the link here. If I get some time I will take a look. Thanks

Comment: @lharby https://pastebin.com/1uwiWAJP

Comment: Hi, @Martin if this is correct and has helped you with your issue please vote on the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in the template on line 408 I simply wrapped the notes component in html comments so they don't get rendered in the browser.

Simply changing:

```
{block:PostNotes}
</center></center>
<div class="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

To:

```
<!--
{block:PostNotes}
<div class="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
{/block:Posts} 
-->
```

Full html template saved here: https://pastebin.com/yva5npcW

I've also removed the redundant 
`</center></center>` that tag is obsolete: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Nothing is being rendered in those erroneous tags.

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]